# Generate OAuth2 token programiticly , No lgoin needed in my case

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I use OAuth2 with asp.net WEB API.

In my case the users will login using only their phone numbers, and they will receive SMS with verification code.

The users confirm their phone number using the verification code with this method:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ConfrimPhoneNumber")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> VerifyPhoneNumber(VerfyPhoneModel Model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        // Verify phone number.
        //..
        //..

        //Get Application User

        //  I need to genereate and return token from here .
    }
```

What i want is to generate access token and refresh token for this user.

thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share what I've got to make this work i collect the answer from different other posts; you can find the link in the end of this answer.

If any one has a comment or idea please share it with us.

**Generate Local access Token with refresh token After user register as Response.**

As [Peter Hedberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207673/peter-hedberg) Answer; We need to make OAuthOptions Puplic and static in the startup class as :

```
 public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions { get; private set; }
```

Then i created helper class to generate local access token and refresh

```
    public async Task<JObject> GenerateLocalAccessToken(ApplicationUser user)
            {
                ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                        OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);


                AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);

                //Create the ticket then the access token
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

                ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(Startup.OAuthServerOptions.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan);

                var accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);


                //Create refresh token
                Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context =
                    new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(
                        Request.GetOwinContext(),
                        Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat, ticket);

                await Startup.OAuthOptions.RefreshTokenProvider.CreateAsync(context);
                properties.Dictionary.Add("refresh_token", context.Token);



                //create the Token Response
                JObject tokenResponse = new JObject(
                                            new JProperty("access_token", accessToken),
                                            new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
                                            new JProperty("expires_in", Startup.OAuthServerOptions.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan.TotalSeconds.ToString()),
                                            new JProperty("refresh_token", context.Token),
                                            new JProperty("userName", user.UserName),
                                            new JProperty(".issued", ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc.ToString()),
                                            new JProperty(".expires", ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.ToString())
            );
                return tokenResponse;

            }
```

There is a problem to use basic context.SerializeTicket in SimpleRefreshTokenProvider CreateAsync method. Message from [Bit Of Technology](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/)

> Seems in the ReceiveAsync method, the context.DeserializeTicket is not
>   returning an Authentication Ticket at all in the external login case.
>   When I look at the context.Ticket property after that call it’s null.
>   Comparing that to the local login flow, the DeserializeTicket method
>   sets the context.Ticket property to an AuthenticationTicket. So the
>   mystery now is how come the DeserializeTicket behaves differently in
>   the two flows. The protected ticket string in the database is created
>   in the same CreateAsync method, differing only in that I call that
>   method manually in the GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse, vs. the Owin
>   middlware calling it normally… And neither SerializeTicket or
>   DeserializeTicket throw an error…

So, you need to use Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer to searizize and deserialize ticket. It will be look like this:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer serializer
                = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer();

token.ProtectedTicket = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(serializer.Serialize(context.Ticket));
```

instead of:

```
token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();
```

And for ReceiveAsync method:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer serializer = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer();
context.SetTicket(serializer.Deserialize(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket)));
```

instead of:

```
context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
```

Please refer to this [Qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23189996/5065193) and this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31318118/5065193) 
thank you [lincx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420723/lincx) and [Giraffe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2746074/giraffe)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you use the default SPA template in Visual Studio. In Startup.Auth.cs you have a static property:

```
public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }
```

If you want to create an OAuth2 token you can use this static reference to generate the token:

```
Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(authenticationTicket);
```